# Compare two IPv6 addresses for equality

Tags: python

I need to compare two IP version6, if there are equal.

It is not a simple string comparison because the same address can be written in multiple ways.
I can't use third-party packages.
For example:

```
2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B
2041:0000:140F::875B:131B
2041:0:140F::875B:131B
```

and from windows ip config can be: `2041:0:140F::875B:131B%11`

Comment: Why can't you use third-party packages?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post you code.

Comment: @James, if he is on Python 3 then it is version specific because Python 3.3+ has the standard library module `ipaddress` and Python 2 doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with `socket` library :

```
import socket
ip1 = "2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B"
ip2 = "2041:0000:140F::875B:131B"
ip3 = "2041:0000:140F::875B:131B"
if socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip1) == socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip2) == socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip3):
     print ("match")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Refrain yourself posting pictures of pure text outputs. Just copy and paste it on your answer instead. Clever solution BTW.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Python 3.3+ you can use the standard library module  [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html):

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ipaddress
>>> a=ipaddress.ip_address('2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B')
>>> b=ipaddress.ip_address('2041:0000:140F::875B:131B')
>>> c=ipaddress.ip_address('2041:0:140F::875B:131B')
>>> a==b==c
True
```

Comment: I need a solution that is compatible with both Python 2 and 3

Comment: Python 2 reached its end of life on January 1st 2020. You better stick with Python 3.3+ and the standard library. If you can use 3rd party libraries, you can go with [`netaddr`](https://pypi.org/project/netaddr/) on Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
import sys

def extend_ipv6(src):
    parts = src.split(":")
    if '%' in parts[-1]:
        parts[-1], _ = parts[-1].split('%', 2)
    n_parts = len(parts)
    out = list()
    for part in parts:
        if len(part) == 0:
            for i in range(8-n_parts+1):
                out.append("0000")
        else:
            out.append("0"*(4-len(part))+part)
    return ":".join(out)

def main():
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print(extend_ipv6(arg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
python3 do.py 2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B 2041:0000:140F::875B:131B 2041:0:140F::875B:131B 2041:0:140F::875B:131B%11
2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B
2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B
2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B
2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B
```

will be this solution enough for your task?